# Transparent areas around rounded corners blocking hovering

Tags: css

I have something set up that looks a little like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/NhAuJ/

The problem is when you hover near the corners of the circle you cannot hover over the background because the div is a square and blocking it. I want the circle div in the middle to be clickable (I'm going to put some things in it) so i dont want to block the cursor from interacting with it using pointer events.

Any ideas how to fix this kind of issue?

Comment: ...but it doesn't on both Chrome and Opera. Is it a bug?

Comment: I can't find any documentation about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I sort of figured it out. For anyone stuck on this, the best I could do was have a bigger circle, and then inside the bigger circle place another circle as its child, i.e.

```
<div class="big-circle">
   <div class="small-circle">

   </div>
</div>
```

Then set pointer-events to none on the big circle and set it to auto on the small circle.

```
.big-circle { 
   pointer-events: none;
}
.small-circle {
   pointer-events: auto;
}
```

It wont entirely fix the problem, but it will improve it. Alternatively use canvas as Slave said.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the only way to achieve this is by html5 canvas. http://jsfiddle.net/NhAuJ/3/

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/